# If all matter is vibration, what does actually vibrate?

Tags: frequency, vibrations

There is a theory, that all matter is energy in vibration in it's core. I have read a lot of articles and watched a lot of videos and documentaries about that topic and they all state, that there is basically no matter and all is vibration. What we call matter is basically the energy in the low states of vibration.

Vibration is energy. Energy is vibration.

What does vibrate then??

Sound is the vibration of the air molecules (mechanical wave of pressure and displacement, through a medium). That means, that the sound is the vibration of matter (air). If matter is also vibration, then air must be a vibration of something else (because how can vibration exist without a medium?). That means, that sound is the vibration of the vibration of something, which should also be a vibration... But what does actually vibrate?

Comment: Do atoms have frequencies from the electron/s revolving around the nucleus? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: This is such a vague question that it's hard to answer. What does "all is vibration" even mean? Can you phrase that in terms of something observable? Or an equation?

Comment: @Jen No. The question is: "what does actually vibrate if all there is - is the vibration?". I mean, vibration in order to exist should have a medium

Comment: @knzhou http://energyfanatics.com/2013/03/19/how-frequency-vibration-create-structures-matter-life/

Comment: That's a crackpot site, don't read it. It's almost 100% wrong.

Comment: @knzhou why? explain please

Comment: @JustMe Sorry but I think knzhou is right. I glimpsed at it and it looks pretty sketchy. Science & religion do not mix. You would have to sacrifice one in order to appease the other usually.

Comment: @Obliv Ok, then what about Tesla's "If you want to find the secrets of the universe, think in terms of energy, frequency and vibration."?

Comment: @JustMe I don't agree with using quotes from well-known people to prove a point. It's not Tesla who is writing that article, it's the author. Even if it were Tesla who wrote it, I'd still say it's likely a crackpot article.

Comment: @Obliv Ok, forget about that article. There is a lot of other in some way, similar information on this topic. Make a research about Tesla, and you will find out, that it is actually his words. And speaking about those words, we get back to the question, that I have asked in the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you're talking about Quantum Field Theory (QFT). In QFT, the fundamental particles making up matter are treated as wave-like excitations of a quantum field. For example, the electron is viewed as an excitation of an electron field; a photon is an excitation of a photon field. The quantum fields are present in every point in spacetime, even in vacuum regions. When you ask "what actually vibrates", I think the medium you're looking for are these quantum fields.

Having said that, the site where you found this quote is filled with pseudoscience. When working with such a source, content may not have any connection to actual science, so you shouldn't be surprised if the scientific community cannot make any reasonable comments.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your responce. It really did explain a lot.